# Howto clear auth basic cache within Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, basic-authentication

How can I clear basic authentication within Safari? My code works well for Chrome, Firefox and others. But not Safari.

I want a logout without the browser login dialog (purely javascript app).

```
            if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') > -1) {
                document.execCommand('ClearAuthenticationCache', 'false');
                //blabla
            }
            else {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/api/v1',
                    username: '_logout',
                    statusCode: {
                        401: function() {
                             //blabla          
                        }
                    }
                }); 
            }
```

Server side:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) && $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] == '_logout') {
          (new \App\Http\Response())
              ->setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="app"')
             ->send(401, 'Unauthorized');
    }
```

It works perfectly with Firefox & co. No browser login prompt.
But I get a login dialog from the Safari browser after hitting the logout button in my application.

Of course it would work if I just do not send the WWW-Authenticate header· But then we don't have real logout, because the browser will not clear the auth cache. And it will send the Authorization header with the "_logout" user every request until I would login again with a new user.

And without sending the WWW-Authenticate, I'm not able to overwrite the Authorization header. The browser will always take the cached value. For example, I login with basic authentication and then logout (The server would just send a 401 without the WWW-Authenticate). Okay now I want to login with a Bearer token, but this would not work cause the browser takes the old cached Basic string.

Da.. Safari......